# What is the best way to specify/access a specific item in a delimited field in Splunk?

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I'm very new to regex and such, I have tried to look for a similar answer but nothing jumping out to me.

I'm trying to refine searches in Splunk using a regex. Is there any way that I can define delimited fields and only focus on that area?
For example:

```
hxxps://example.com/examplefolder/examplestring/
```

I wanted to match conditions only within <examplestring> field, I understand that using $ will set the end of the string however I need to only match if it is the 'fourth' field from the start of the string, if the delimiter was '/'

So far I am just using `\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,15}\/$` to match characters between 10 and 15 in length, it matches based on that last field but other entries match this such as:

```
hxxps://example.com/examplestring2/
```

Is there a recommendation as to how I can use regex to focus the matching to a set 'field' (field4) of the string using '/' as a delimiter please?

```
hxxps:/<field1>/<field2>/<field3>/<field4>/<field5>
```

I have confused myself just trying to explain what I'm after so please feel free to probe me I'm making no sense.

Comment: The way is to start the pattern with `^` and describing the "three first fields" and then to build the description of your fourth field with a subpattern that forbids the character `/`. Something like `^http://(?:[^/]*/){3}/yoursubpattern`

Comment: Try not to ask how to do so and so *using x* (in this case *Regex*). *X*, or *Regex*, may not always be the best way to approach your problem to begin with. Have you considered just splitting the string on `'/'` and taking the 4th or 5th index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using a combination of the [`eval` functions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/CommonEvalFunctions) `split` and `mvindex`:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp url=*
| eval url_parts=split(url,"/")
| eval segment=mvindex(url_parts,4)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well and then I used regex later to refine the answer. 
Much appreciated!